# Symfony2: Removing entity from middle of collection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

## 1. Overview

I want to be able to remove an entity from a collection using a symfony2 Form.

#### 1.1 Problem

I can add new entities to the collection, and remove them, as long as the entity being added or removed is at the **end of the collection**. As soon as I remove one from the start or middle I get the following error:

When I try to do this I get this error:

> Neither the property "id" nor one of the methods
>   "addId()"/"removeId()", "setId()", "id()", "__set()" or "__call()"
>   exist and have public access in class
>   "ApiBundle\Entity\Data\Column".

#### 1.2 Code

Here is all the relevant code.

**Data**

```
/**
 * Data
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="data__data")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ApiBundle\Repository\Data\DataRepository")
 */
class Data
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Column", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $columns;

    /**
     * Initialise the array collections
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->columns = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $columns
     */
    public function setColumns($columns)
    {
        $this->columns = $columns;
    }

    /**
     * @param Column $column
     */
    public function addColumn($column)
    {
        $column->setParent($this);
        $this->columns->add($column);
    }

    /**
     * @param Column $column
     */
    public function removeColumn($column)
    {
        $this->columns->removeElement($column);
    }
}
```

**Column**

```
/**
 * Data
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="data__column")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Column
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Data
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Data", inversedBy="columns")
     */
    protected $parent;

    /**
     * @return Data
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * @param Data $parent
     */
    public function setParent($parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }
}
```

**DataFormType**

```
class DataFormType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('id')
            ->add('columns', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new ColumnFormType(),
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ApiBundle\Entity\Data\Data',
            'csrf_protection' => false
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'data';
    }

}
```

**ColumnFormType**

```
class ColumnFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('id');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ApiBundle\Entity\Data\Column',
            'csrf_protection' => false
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'data_column';
    }

}
```

***I have removed some code from these snippets for clarity***

#### 1.3 Conclusion

Like I say, I get no problems when adding or deleting from the end of the collection. But as soon as it is anywhere else it errors out.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try to debug it by printing the $_POST/form datas received and check if it what you expected?

Comment: @caCtus - Yeah, its sending the right stuff as far as I can tell. I mean, when deleting. it just doesnt send those Columns. So its an array with thise items missing.

Comment: Uhm, your id property is an ORM Id, when you generate entities there are no setters methods by default since it's the ORM that handles Ids. Also your entities are missing getters for the ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the lack of the collection key preserving.

`CollectionType` is high tought with `ResizeListener`. It fills the collection form with subforms:

```
public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData();

    ...

    // Then add all rows again in the correct order
    foreach ($data as $name => $value) {
        $form->add($name, $this->type, array_replace(array(
            'property_path' => '['.$name.']',
        ), $this->options));
    }
}
```

So the every subform is mapped to the collection object (underlying data) and has the name that applies to collection index, e.g. '[0]', '[1]'. When you delete elements from the collection `ResizeListener` removes redundant subforms.

```
public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $data = $event->getData();
    ...

    // Remove all empty rows
    if ($this->allowDelete) {
        foreach ($form as $name => $child) {
            if (!isset($data[$name])) {
                $form->remove($name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lets say there were `data[columns][0][id]=1, data[columns][1][id]=2, data[columns][2][id]=3`.

When you remove an element from the end - all is fine.  There comes `data[columns][0][id]=1, data[columns][1][id]=2` with corresponding content. Then the subform `[2]` will be deleted and then the element with index 2 will be deleted from the collection.

When you remove an element not at the end and you don't preserve keys - the error occurs. For example you send `data[columns][0][id]=2, data[columns][1][id]=3`. `ResizeListener` will delete the subform with index `[2]`. Underlying data will be overrided for the rest of subforms (`[0]`, `[1]`) and their child (`id`). Most nested subforms are processed first.

```
 [0] (Column)
    [id]
        1 => 2
 [1] (Column)
    [id]
        2 => 3
```

Then `PropertyPathMapper` will detect that `id` subform's data is not equals to Column's `id` property value (this is underlying data of the `[0]`):

```
public function mapFormsToData($forms, &$data)
{
    ...
            if (!is_object($data) || !$config->getByReference() || $form->getData() !== $this->propertyAccessor->getValue($data, $propertyPath)) {
                $this->propertyAccessor->setValue($data, $propertyPath, $form->getData());
            }
    ...
}
```

It will make `PropertyAccessor` to set new `id` value to `Column` object. The last one will throw exception as there is no way to set new `id` to Column (no setter, property is not public, etc).

**Solution:** To preserve key order. If you get `data[columns][0][id]=1, data[columns][1][id]=2, data[columns][2][id]=3` and you delete first element you should send `data[columns][1][id]=2, data[columns][2][id]=3`

**PS** Key order preserving for Forms is good practice for all cases. It will prevent you from redundant `UPDATE` queries and loops.

Comment: Thanks, this was precisely the problem!